# How to hook into publish post events in wordpress 4.7.5

Tags: plugin-development

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'a_new_post', 10, 3 );

function a_new_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status )
    return;

if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type )
    return; // restrict the filter to a specific post type

// do something awesome
}
```

this code will not allow me to hook into a published post. Is there any code that allows me to hook into published post.

Answer (score 1):

Use {status}_{post_type} hook like:

```
function a_new_post( $postID, $post ) {
    // your awesome stuff goes here
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'a_new_post', 10, 2 );
```

It will fire your action when post's status will change from anything to 'publish'.